# C# - Trying to add row values to list throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, enumerable, getvalue

I want to store the values of the columns, i.e. column names, and the row values of a specific row into two seperate lists. `Provider` and `Document` are both of `List<string>`. But since there is a type conflict with `Document` I'm using `var Document`, so the compiler accepts it.

The following code works perfectly fine until `var Document = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).Select(dr.GetValue).ToList();`

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(abfrage, conn);
OleDbDataReader dr;
try
{
    conn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Provider = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount)
                         .Select(dr.GetName)
                         .ToList();
    // Following line will throw exception
    var Document = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount)
                             .Select(dr.GetValue)
                             .ToList();
    dr.Close();
    dr.Dispose();
}          
catch (System.InvalidOperationException inv)
{
    MessageBox.Show(inv.Message);
    throw;
}
```

The first list has the column names correctly stored but the other one throws an `InvalidOperationException` and says, that there are no values in either the rows or the columns. This is correct for some columns (they're empty). I tested it with another DB-Table where every column/row has a value but I get the same exception here.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here are two screenshots which show the read values by the reader.

The first one with the column names (values are greyed out, it's sensitive data):
[first results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOfa3.png)

The second one with the values of the whole row:
[read values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmRIp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `dr.Read()` to read the first row from the results.

Also, your `Document` in that code is a local variable that gets thrown away.  I am guessing you want to assign it to a property of the same name?  You will also need to cast the result of `dr.GetValue()` to a string.

I think you will want to initialise both `Document` and `Provider` and the call `AddRange` method instead of assigning them to the result.

Comment: I tried `while (dr.Read())
                {


                   // var Document = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).Select(dr.GetValue).ToList());
                }` and indeed it stores/adds the values to `var Document`. Also, like you said, `Document` gets thrown away. I tried casting it but I'm not sure how to manage that. I also tried your suggestion to call the `AddRange()`-Method without success.

Comment: I think I got it. This code is working and `Document` keeps the results: `IEnumerable<object> Document;` and `Document = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).Select(dr.GetValue).ToList();`. Is this the right/best way to do this?

Comment: @Allix, yes, that way will work fine.  You could make Document an IList<object>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Enter Connection String Here");
            string abfrage = "Enter Query Here";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(abfrage, conn);
            OleDbDataReader dr;
            List<string> Provider = new List<string>();
            int colIndex = 3;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    Provider.Add(dr.GetString(colIndex));
                }

                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
            }

            catch (System.InvalidOperationException inv)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(inv.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `while (dr.Read())
                {

                    Provider.Add(dr.GetString(colIndex));
                }`
but again it throws the same exception. I don't really get it since the first list gets the right results.

Comment: This seems to be reading in all the rows to Provider, whereas the OP wanted to only read all the values from one row.

Comment: @RobinSalih Yes, correct. My query looks for a specific value in a row (let's say ID 5) and returns the associated row with all the column values.

Comment: ExcuteReader isn't returned any rows.  There is something wrong with the connection or query (command text).

Comment: I'll post two screenshots in the OP, so you can see what values are read by the reader.